# How synchronization helps in variable visibility?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

```
public class NoVisibility {
   private static boolean ready;
   private static int number;
   private static class ReaderThread extends Thread {
      public void run() {
         while (!ready)
            Thread.yield();
         System.out.println(number);
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       new ReaderThread().start();
       number = 42;
       ready = true;
   }
}
```

According to "Java Concurrency in Practice", it may be possible that it will print 0 as write to ready might be made visible to the reader thread before write to a number or program never terminate at all because it does not use adequate synchronization. It is not guaranteed that values of ready and number written by main thread will be visible to reader thread.

How is it possible? Program will be run sequentially by a thread and it first writes to number and then ready variable. Isn't it? And how can this program could loop forever?

Answer (score 1):

There are no guarantees that by changing a variable in one thread, other threads will see the results of those changes. Technically there is no happens-before relation between them and thus no guarantees (whilst in practice you'll see the changes almost all the time).

That's why the thread may run forever.

Secondly, why sometimes 0 ?

Well the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) says that

> Writes in one thread that are in a data race with reads in another
>   thread may, for example, appear to occur out of order to those reads.

Which means that your

```
number = 42;
ready = true;
```

Can occur in any order. Now it's more likely they'll appear in order, but again there's no guarantees.

You could fix it by changing the variables to be volatile, in which case the writes will always be visible to the readers or by making the code where you mutate state a critical section (see the book). In general I feel using too many volatile variables is a bit of a hack, so you should try and use them sparingly, for things like thread "running" variables.

```
public class NoVisibility {
    private static volatile boolean ready;
    private static volatile int number;

    private static class ReaderThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            while (!ready)
                Thread.yield();
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ReaderThread().start();
        number = 42;
        ready = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: why there are issues in using too many volatile variables? Or related question to this is why can't we replace synchronized code with volatile variables?

Comment: Because volatile won't "stretch" across blocks of code. It's fine for atomic mutation of a single variable but not for example to have access to multiple variables be seen as a single atomic operation.

Comment: volatile won't "stretch" across blocks of code - I am sorry but I didn't get that. Can you please explain this? Also, I don't understand how access to multiple variables can cause issues in single atomic operation.

Comment: volatile is a bit like synchronizing just a single variable. If you have multiple vars that you need to synchronize together then it won't work. Think about doing a transfer from one bank account to another. You need to "lock" access to both accounts. Volatile won't do that.

Answer (score 0):

If ready is not marked as 'volatile' than the ReaderThread might check its value (as 0).
It later does not check again about ready's value because it assume it has not changed.

The volatile keyword instructs the compiler not to have such assumptions at all and that the variable's value might change under his feet.

Comment: why there are issues in using too many volatile variables? Or related question to this is why can't we replace synchronized code with volatile variables?